# I need to join two tables in php

Tags: php

I need to insert image row from table 'users2' to 'allbets'. But suddenlly this code don't working and I don't know why.. What is wrong with this?

```
$q2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO allbets (image) SELECT users2.image FROM users2 WHERE username = ?');
$q2->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['name']);
$q2 -> execute();
```

Comment: Probably your query is wrong, you should Google it and find some docs

Comment: "this code don't working" is hardly a precise problem statement

Comment: The "suddenly" is what makes me nervous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did not suddenly stop working, it never could have worked with its present query syntax. Change the query to this -

```
$q2 = $pdo -> prepare('INSERT INTO allbets (user, bet, komanda, teams, cof, data, image) VALUES ($user, $bet, $komanda, $teams, $cof, $data, (SELECT `users2`.`image` FROM `users2` WHERE `username` = ?));
```

Do yourself a service and error checking to your PHP code and to your PDO. This will let you know where to look when errors occur.

Comment: How should I include this line into this:

$q2 = $pdo -> prepare('INSERT INTO allbets (user, bet, komanda, teams, cof, data, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ');

Comment: You need to use the VALUES syntax or the query will never work.

Comment: Why the image is not inserting?

                            $img = $pdo->query('SELECT `users2`.`image` FROM `users2` WHERE `username` = $user');

        $q2 = $pdo -> prepare('INSERT INTO allbets (user, bet, komanda, teams, cof, data, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ');
        $q2 -> bindValue(1, $_SESSION['name']);
        $q2 -> bindValue(2, $bet);
        $q2 -> bindValue(3, $komanda);
        $q2 -> bindValue(4, $teams);
        $q2 -> bindValue(5, $lose);
        $q2 -> bindValue(6, time());
        $q2 -> bindValue(7, $img);
        $q2->execute();

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Have you added error checking? We need that to see what the problem is.

Comment: There is no errors. All fields have been inserted except image. I need to somehow concate that CODE: SELECT `users2`.`image` FROM `users2` WHERE `username` = ? ?

Comment: What is in the image column?

Comment: Its blank. The select query is good. I checked it. I need to implement that one select query into that INSERT INTO query.. But I don't know how..